# What Is The Scope Of Continue In A Nested Python For Loop?

Tags: python, for-loop, scope, nested, continue

When using nested for loops, if I use continue inside the inner nested for loop, does the scope of that continue only apply to the inner loop or will it continue the outer loop?

Note: For what I am working on I only want the continue to affect the nested loop

```
b = ["hello"] * 5
d = ["world"] * 10

for a in b: # Outer Loop
    x = 1 + 1
    for c in d: # Nested Loop
        if c:
            x += 1
        else: 
            continue # Does this affect the Nested Loop or the Outer Loop
```

Comment: It only affects the inner loop

Comment: It's [clearly documented](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-continue-statement): "It continues with the next cycle of the nearest enclosing loop."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It only affects the inner loop.

Answer (score 3):

Loop control keywords like `break` and `continue` only affect the closest loop in scope to them. So if you have a loop nested in another loop, the keyword targets whatever loop it is immediately within, not loops farther up the line.